# implementing a scheduler (timer) in c++

Tags: c++, timer, scheduler, c++-chrono

I have a dump of network packages recorded with their timestamps (grab-times). I would like to re-play the packages by sending them in the same pace as they have arrived.

The question is: is there a specific facility in C++ to implement a scheduler?

The usual answer would go, emit the first package and than wait for the difference between the timestamps:

```
auto now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
auto diff = next_package_timestamp - current_package_timestamp;
std::this_thread::sleep_for(diff);
```

However, I dislike this solution for several reasons:

1. It does not account for short waiting times. What happens if the processing of the event takes longer than the difference between the two timestamps (**diff**)? Do I have to use a separate thread? Do I have to rely on signals for the computation?
2. It does not account for long waiting times. What would happen if the waiting time is several weaks? Would the time remain synchronized using NTP? Would I need to rely on the quartz clock?

I would prefer a

```
template <class Functor>
launch_at_specific_time(const time_t & time, Functor & functor);
```

type of function which would invoke the functor at the specific *wall time*.

Is there a C++ way of implementing the Timer? Is there a generic library, that has taken up the task?

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Check this link for a scheduler without polling
  : https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/189836/multi-threaded-time-scheduler-without-polling

Comment: Have you looked into `sleep_until`?